# how to monitor hazelcast cluster on production environment using hazelcast management center

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-aggregate

I have an application which is deployed on aws ec2 instance. We are using hazelcast cache to store certain tokens for user management. How to monitor this application from hazelcast management center.

Currently I am not able to connect to this node using hazelcast management center setup on local via IP address.

Do I need to install or setup anything else for such requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Hazelcast Management Center: Getting Started](https://docs.hazelcast.com/management-center/4.2021.03/getting-started.html). It explains how to start Management Center and how to connect it to your Hazelcast cluster.

In short, you need to start Management Center, open it with your browser, and click "Add Cluster Config". Then, you can monitor and manage your Hazelcast cluster with the Management Center Application.

Comment: That's working for local environment. Same is not working for production environment.

Comment: What is the issue you get on production?

Comment: for production environment my IP gets change every time and every time a new instance is there.. My management center is on common node and the applicatin n other nodes doesn't get connected/shown in management center

Comment: If the IPs of your Hazelcast members change all the time, then you need to use one of the Discovery Mechanism described here: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/clusters/discovery-mechanisms.html